# How to simulate a long time spent in background state for my iOS app?

Tags: ios, background

I'm having issues with my app not properly restoring its previous state after it has spent some time in the background ( I'd say around 15 minutes ).

To work on that bug, I usually compile my code, put my app in background and wait around 15 minutes. Then I select my app again and I can use it with the debugger activated.

That's not efficient at all, so I was wondering if there was a way to simulate the fact that an app spends some time in the background.

Thanks!

Comment: Try enabling the phone settings option: Settings -> Developer Options -> Don't keep activities

Comment: This is an iOS app unfortunately